# Why did composer install oauth2-client with different directory names and files

Tags: composer-php

I am new to composer and I used it to install the oauth2-client.  I think I am having some sort of misunderstanding about how this is supposed to work.

From thephpleague github page I installed from the command line using
`composer require league/oauth2-client`

This added files to /usr/local/bin/vendor/league/oauth2-client.
The file structure looks the same as it does on github, except I don't have all the same files.

And the php in the files is looking for files in \League\OAuth2, so I am getting errors that it can't find included files, because I don't have that directory.

Did I do it wrong, or am I just not getting something?

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is the PHP namespace separator, not the directory separator.

In the `composer.json` for oauth2 from TheLeague, this is the `autoload` directive:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "League\\OAuth2\\Client\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

It says that the code inside of `src` directory is in the `League\OAuth2\Client` namespace.

Composer follows [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) with regards to namespacing and autoloading, so check that out if you want to know what goes on.

UPDATE:
If you've installed other League extensions, like `oauth2-facebook`, it will install itself into the same `src` directory - because of the autoload directive in `composer.json`.

Why?
Well, because of the namespace, you will find 'Facebook' in the `League\OAuth2\Client\Provider` namespace.
Because of PSR-4, this means that they need to go into the same directory, even though they are different packages.

That is the reason why you'll see `Facebook.php` in `src/Providers` directory. Check the `oauth2-facebook` [repository](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-facebook)

You probably have `required` oauth2-facebook and oauth2-google, or one of your other required packages requires it. It rarely just add themselves. :)

Comment: OK, I guess I was a bit fuzzy on how namespaces work, I'll need to look more into that.  But how about the files being different?  For example I want to use the file I see on github, oauth2-client/src/Provider/GenericProvider.php.  But when I look in the same path on my server all the files in that directory are different.

Comment: What do you mean by *'all the files are different'* ? What version are you using? Check the `.gitattribues` of the repository - the `test` and the `docs` dir are excluded. All the rest is included in the package.

Comment: on github in src/Provider there are 4 files, AbstractProvider.php, GenericProvider.php, etc.
When I log into my server in src/Provider the files are Google.php, Facebook.php, etc

Comment: "UPDATE: If you've installed other League extensions, like oauth2-facebook, it will install itself into the same src directory - because of the autoload directive in composer.json."

That's not true. You will end up with two different `src/` directories (one in `vendor/league/oauth2-client` and the other one in `vendor/league/oauth2-facebook).